# Button when clicked, the expected result is not achieved

Tags: javascript, html, button

When I click the button:

```
<button class="button" style="width: 352px;" onclick="limpartexto1()">Limpar Texto 1</button>
```

Circled in red, in theory it should clear the texts written in the text bars and press the Radar 1 button. However, when I click on the button, nothing happens.

Error indicated in dev tools by Google Chrome:

[image]

I'd like some help figuring out why this is happening, I can't find the error.

[image]

```
            <div class="column left">
                <form action="" method="post" id="url-setter1">
                    <button class="button" id="botaoradar1" onclick="radarzinho1()">Radar 1</button>
                    <input type="text" name="url1" id="url1" style="width: 283px;" />
                    <iframe id="the-frame1" width="347" height="282" src=""></iframe>
                    <p></p>
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                        (function radarzinho1() {
                            "use strict";
                            var url_setter = document.getElementById('url-setter1'), url = document.getElementById('url1'), the_iframe = document.getElementById('the-frame1');
                            url_setter.onsubmit = function (event) {
                                try {
                                    let link = document.getElementById("url1").value;
                                    let value1 = link.split("OB_EV")[1];
                                    value1 = value1.split("/")[0];
                                        event.preventDefault();
                                        the_iframe.src = "https://sports.staticcache.org/scoreboards/scoreboards-football/index.html?eventId=" + value1;
                                } catch (e) {
                                        event.preventDefault();
                                        the_iframe.src = "https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/26/26547.png";
                                }
                            };
                        }());
                    </script>
                <form method="post" target="imgChart1">
                    <input class="button" type="submit" value="Chart 1" />
                    <input type="text" id="ChartBar1" name="ChartBar1" style="width: 285px;"><br>
                <img src="https://sitedeapostas-com.imgix.net/assets/local/Company/logos/betfair_logo_transp.png?auto=compress%2Cformat&fit=clip&q=75&w=263&s=c1691b4034fd0c4526d27ffe8b1e839c" name="Chart 1"/>
                <p></p>
                <form  action="" method="post" id="ClearText1">
                    <button class="button" style="width: 352px;" onclick="limpartexto1()">Limpar Texto 1</button>
                </form>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    function limpartexto1() {
                        var btn = document.getElementById('ClearText1');
                        btn.onclick = function(e){
                        e.preventDefault(); 
                        document.getElementById('ChartBar1').value="";
                        document.getElementById('url1').value="";
                        document.getElementById('botaoradar1').click();};
                    }
                </script>
            </div>
```

**Note: I'll leave the complete project script to make it easier for anyone who can help me:**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            {
            box-sizing: border-box;
            }
            .column {
            float: left;
            width: 355;
            }
            .left {
            }
            .middle {
            }
            .middle2 {
            }
            .right {
            }
            .row:after {
            content: "";
            display: table;
            clear: both;
            }
            
            .button {
            background-color: #33ccff;
            color: black;
            font-weight: bold;
            }
            
            body {
            overflow: hidden;
            }
        </style>
        <script>
            if ( window.history.replaceState ) {
            window.history.replaceState( null, null, window.location.href );
            }
        </script>
        <script language="JavaScript">
            let intervalID
            window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
                intervalID = setInterval(refreshIt, 500); // refresh every 0.5 secs
            })
            
            function refreshIt() {
                if (!document.images) return;
                // if want to stop the interval from repeating
                // if (!document.images)  clearInterval(intervalID)
                document.images['Chart 1'].src = ChartBar1.value;
                document.images['Chart 2'].src = ChartBar2.value;
                document.images['Chart 3'].src = ChartBar3.value;
                document.images['Chart 4'].src = ChartBar4.value;
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body style="background-color:black;">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="column left">
                <form action="" method="post" id="url-setter1">
                    <button class="button" id="botaoradar1" onclick="radarzinho1()">Radar 1</button>
                    <input type="text" name="url1" id="url1" style="width: 283px;" />
                    <iframe id="the-frame1" width="347" height="282" src=""></iframe>
                    <p></p>
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                        (function radarzinho1() {
                            "use strict";
                            var url_setter = document.getElementById('url-setter1'), url = document.getElementById('url1'), the_iframe = document.getElementById('the-frame1');
                            url_setter.onsubmit = function (event) {
                                try {
                                    let link = document.getElementById("url1").value;
                                    let value1 = link.split("OB_EV")[1];
                                    value1 = value1.split("/")[0];
                                        event.preventDefault();
                                        the_iframe.src = "https://sports.staticcache.org/scoreboards/scoreboards-football/index.html?eventId=" + value1;
                                } catch (e) {
                                        event.preventDefault();
                                        the_iframe.src = "https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/26/26547.png";
                                }
                            };
                        }());
                    </script>
                <form method="post" target="imgChart1">
                    <input class="button" type="submit" value="Chart 1" />
                    <input type="text" id="ChartBar1" name="ChartBar1" style="width: 285px;"><br>
                <img src="https://sitedeapostas-com.imgix.net/assets/local/Company/logos/betfair_logo_transp.png?auto=compress%2Cformat&fit=clip&q=75&w=263&s=c1691b4034fd0c4526d27ffe8b1e839c" name="Chart 1"/>
                <p></p>
                <form  action="" method="post" id="ClearText1">
                    <button class="button" style="width: 352px;" onclick="limpartexto1()">Limpar Texto 1</button>
                </form>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    function limpartexto1() {
                        var btn = document.getElementById('ClearText1');
                        btn.onclick = function(e){
                        e.preventDefault(); 
                        document.getElementById('ChartBar1').value="";
                        document.getElementById('url1').value="";
                        document.getElementById('botaoradar1').click();};
                    }
                </script>
            </div>
            <div class="column middle">
                <form action="" method="post" id="url-setter2">
                    <button class="button" id="botaoradar2" onclick="radarzinho2()">Radar 2</button>
                    <input type="text" name="url2" id="url2" style="width: 283px;" />
                    <iframe id="the-frame2" width="347" height="282" src=""></iframe>
                    <p></p>
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                        (function radarzinho2() {
                            "use strict";
                            var url_setter = document.getElementById('url-setter2'), url = document.getElementById('url2'), the_iframe = document.getElementById('the-frame2');
                            url_setter.onsubmit = function (event) {
                                try {
                                    let link = document.getElementById("url2").value;
                                    let value2 = link.split("OB_EV")[1];
                                    value2 = value2.split("/")[0];
                                        event.preventDefault();
                                        the_iframe.src = "https://sports.staticcache.org/scoreboards/scoreboards-football/index.html?eventId=" + value2;
                                } catch (e) {
                                        event.preventDefault();
                                        the_iframe.src = "https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/26/26547.png";
                                }
                            };
                        }());
                    </script>
                <form method="post" target="imgChart2">
                    <input class="button" type="submit" value="Chart 2" />
                    <input type="text" id="ChartBar2" name="ChartBar2" style="width: 285px;"><br>
                <img src="https://sitedeapostas-com.imgix.net/assets/local/Company/logos/betfair_logo_transp.png?auto=compress%2Cformat&fit=clip&q=75&w=263&s=c1691b4034fd0c4526d27ffe8b1e839c" name="Chart 2"/>
                <p></p>
                <form  action="" method="post" id="ClearText2">
                    <button class="button" style="width: 352px;" onclick="limpartexto2()">Limpar Texto 2</button>
                </form>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    function limpartexto2() {
                        var btn = document.getElementById('ClearText2');
                        btn.onclick = function(e){
                        e.preventDefault(); 
                        document.getElementById('ChartBar2').value="";
                        document.getElementById('url2').value="";
                        document.getElementById('botaoradar2').click();};
                    }
                </script>
            </div>
            <div class="column middle2">
                <form action="" method="post" id="url-setter3">
                    <button class="button" id="botaoradar3" onclick="radarzinho3()">Radar 3</button>
                    <input type="text" name="url3" id="url3" style="width: 283px;" />
                    <iframe id="the-frame3" width="347" height="282" src=""></iframe>
                    <p></p>
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                        (function radarzinho3() {
                            "use strict";
                            var url_setter = document.getElementById('url-setter3'), url = document.getElementById('url3'), the_iframe = document.getElementById('the-frame3');
                            url_setter.onsubmit = function (event) {
                                try {
                                    let link = document.getElementById("url3").value;
                                    let value3 = link.split("OB_EV")[1];
                                    value3 = value3.split("/")[0];
                                        event.preventDefault();
                                        the_iframe.src = "https://sports.staticcache.org/scoreboards/scoreboards-football/index.html?eventId=" + value3;
                                } catch (e) {
                                        event.preventDefault();
                                        the_iframe.src = "https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/26/26547.png";
                                }
                            };
                        }());
                    </script>
                <form method="post" target="imgChart3">
                    <input class="button" type="submit" value="Chart 3" />
                    <input type="text" id="ChartBar3" name="ChartBar3" style="width: 285px;"><br>
                <img src="https://sitedeapostas-com.imgix.net/assets/local/Company/logos/betfair_logo_transp.png?auto=compress%2Cformat&fit=clip&q=75&w=263&s=c1691b4034fd0c4526d27ffe8b1e839c" name="Chart 3"/>
                <p></p>
                <form  action="" method="post" id="ClearText3">
                    <button class="button" style="width: 352px;" onclick="limpartexto3()">Limpar Texto 3</button>
                </form>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    function limpartexto3() {
                        var btn = document.getElementById('ClearText3');
                        btn.onclick = function(e){
                        e.preventDefault(); 
                        document.getElementById('ChartBar3').value="";
                        document.getElementById('url3').value="";
                        document.getElementById('botaoradar3').click();};
                    }
                </script>
            </div>
            <div class="column right">
                <form action="" method="post" id="url-setter4">
                    <button class="button" id="botaoradar4" onclick="radarzinho4()">Radar 4</button>
                    <input type="text" name="url4" id="url4" style="width: 283px;" />
                    <iframe id="the-frame4" width="347" height="282" src=""></iframe>
                    <p></p>
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                        (function radarzinho4() {
                            "use strict";
                            var url_setter = document.getElementById('url-setter4'), url = document.getElementById('url4'), the_iframe = document.getElementById('the-frame4');
                            url_setter.onsubmit = function (event) {
                                try {
                                    let link = document.getElementById("url4").value;
                                    let value4 = link.split("OB_EV")[1];
                                    value4 = value4.split("/")[0];
                                        event.preventDefault();
                                        the_iframe.src = "https://sports.staticcache.org/scoreboards/scoreboards-football/index.html?eventId=" + value4;
                                } catch (e) {
                                        event.preventDefault();
                                        the_iframe.src = "https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/26/26547.png";
                                }
                            };
                        }());
                    </script>
                <form method="post" target="imgChart4">
                    <input class="button" type="submit" value="Chart 4" />
                    <input type="text" id="ChartBar4" name="ChartBar4" style="width: 285px;"><br>
                <img src="https://sitedeapostas-com.imgix.net/assets/local/Company/logos/betfair_logo_transp.png?auto=compress%2Cformat&fit=clip&q=75&w=263&s=c1691b4034fd0c4526d27ffe8b1e839c" name="Chart 4"/>
                <p></p>
                <form  action="" method="post" id="ClearText4">
                    <button class="button" style="width: 352px;" onclick="limpartexto4()">Limpar Texto 4</button>
                </form>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    function limpartexto4() {
                        var btn = document.getElementById('ClearText4');
                        btn.onclick = function(e){
                        e.preventDefault(); 
                        document.getElementById('ChartBar4').value="";
                        document.getElementById('url4').value="";
                        document.getElementById('botaoradar4').click();};
                    }
                </script>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should try to add only the relevant part. This whole script is too overwhelming for a lot of users.

Comment: Also, it does not seem that you are trying to do some actions on click of your button. Inside that function you have attached one more event handler which is for the `form`. Not sure if that is what you want to do

Comment: Hello my friend, I put the complete script to make it easier for anyone to copy it, so it can run without having to write lines of script to complete the important part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing this function code:

```
 function limpartexto3() {
                       document.getElementById('ChartBar3').value="";
                        document.getElementById('url3').value="";
                        document.getElementById('botaoradar3').click();};
                    }
```

Instead of attaching one more event handler you should simply call your actions on click of this button.

One more observation is the use of IIFE. These functions are created in a separate scope and you cannot use them as your event handlers.

Use this:

```
function radarzinho1() {
                            "use strict";
                            var url_setter = document.getElementById('url-setter1'), url = document.getElementById('url1'), the_iframe = document.getElementById('the-frame1');
                            url_setter.onsubmit = function (event) {
                                try {
                                    let link = document.getElementById("url1").value;
                                    let value1 = link.split("OB_EV")[1];
                                    value1 = value1.split("/")[0];
                                        event.preventDefault();
                                        the_iframe.src = "https://sports.staticcache.org/scoreboards/scoreboards-football/index.html?eventId=" + value1;
                                } catch (e) {
                                        event.preventDefault();
                                        the_iframe.src = "https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/26/26547.png";
                                }
                            };
                        }
```

Suggest you to start small and then add these complex functionalities.

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/tusharshahi/pen/RwVVeGd?editors=1011)

Comment: Hello my friend, unfortunately when I click on the button, nothing is still happening.

Comment: I would suggest you to create a *minimal* reproducible example. More importantly add `console.log()` everywhere in your code to see what is happening. Is this function called, are these statement run etc.

Comment: Check this codepen - https://codepen.io/tusharshahi/pen/RwVVeGd?editors=1011. Seems to work.